# PostgreSQL - Make query using index

Tags: postgresql, indexing

- Hi, I have a problem with indexing in PostgreSQL. My problem is as follow:
- I have a table.

```
CREATE TABLE services (
    id BIGINT,
    cost FLOAT,
    fee FLOAT
);
```

- I want to make this query uses index

```
SELECT * FROM services WHERE cost - ${P} * fee BETWEEN ${L} AND ${R};
```

- `${P}`, `${L}`, `${R}` are arbitrary real numbers and entered by users;
- `0.0 <= ${P} <= 0.85` and `fee <= cost` so `cost - ${P} * fee > 0`

Thank you very much.

Comment: It is going to be very hard to get that to use an index in a meaningful way.  They can even be negative?

Comment: @jjanes I edited my question. They always are positive.

Comment: IMHO your condition will not be sargable.

Comment: You might be able to define a [spatial index](http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html) on `point(cost, fee)` and use [geometric functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-geometry.html) to find those being contained in the polygon that describes the solution to your equation.

Comment: Can the percentage (fraction, to be precise) take all possible values?

Comment: @Bergi Thank you so much. I think your solution is correct ^^

Comment: @Thomas If you can make this work, please [write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) - I'm curious myself how exactly this would look